# How to find the smallest dimensional space a metric space on finitely many points can be embedded into?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

So if I have $n$ points $p_1,\dots,p_n$ and their distances are given, how can I find the smallest dimensional surface it can be embedded into?

Obviously I could associate it with a simplex, so that would work, but clearly it's not always the best option. I guess in the case of the discrete metric, we cannot really do much better, but for example if we record the distances of cities on earth, I should be able to embed it into a $3$ dimensional space.

How would you approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See wiki entry of [distance geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry) In particular, section $4$ about [Menger characterization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry#Menger_characterization_theorem) There are algorithms that implement this efficiently but I don't remember where I see that.